# What's the difference between `var a chan int` and `a := make(chan int)`?

Tags: go

Today I'm learning channels and goroutine of go. And I met some phenomenon which confuses me.

My go file looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func testRoutine(number int, channel chan int) {
    channel <- number
}


func main() {
//    var a chan int
    a := make(chan int)
    b := make(chan int)
    go testRoutine(1, a)
    go testRoutine(2, b)

    c, d := <-a, <-b
    fmt.Printf("%d %d\n", c, d)
}
```

it works well when I used syntax `a := make(chan int)`.

But when I changed `a := make(chan int)` to `var a chan int`, I got panic report:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive (nil chan)]:
main.main()
    /Users/marioluisgarcia/Local/practice/go/cache/var_make_diff.go:19 +0xc7

goroutine 18 [chan send (nil chan)]:
main.testRoutine(0x1, 0x0)
    /Users/marioluisgarcia/Local/practice/go/cache/var_make_diff.go:8 +0x3f
created by main.main
    /Users/marioluisgarcia/Local/practice/go/cache/var_make_diff.go:16 +0x7c

goroutine 19 [chan send]:
main.testRoutine(0x2, 0xc42008a060)
    /Users/marioluisgarcia/Local/practice/go/cache/var_make_diff.go:8 +0x3f
created by main.main
    /Users/marioluisgarcia/Local/practice/go/cache/var_make_diff.go:17 +0xa7
```

So, is there any difference between `var a chan int` and `a := make(chan int)`, and why this panic phenomenon was triggered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that `var name type` creates a variable named `name` of type `type` set to the **default** value for that type.  This means that `var a chan int` creates a channel such that `a == nil`.

`var a chan int = make(chan int)` and `a := make(chan int)` are, however, the same.

Comment: var a = make(chan int) would also be the same

Answer (score 12):

`a := make(chan int)` creates unbuffered channel. That channel with zero buffer. You can send data through it.

`var a chan int` creates channel variable and sets it to default value which is **nil**. And a **nil** channel is always blocking, that's why your program is deadlocked. You can not send data in **nil** channel.

If you print the values, you will see the difference.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i chan int
    fmt.Println(i)
    a := make(chan int)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/Bxr6qRfNqZd

Comment: A simply in-depth answer, unbuffered and nil channel. 
`var a chan int` and `a := make(chan int)` are not the exact same thing.

Comment: We can write data to nil channels. I think something else is happening under the hood. Check the code https://go.dev/play/p/u1yokjA0hjD

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal i got err running you program: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!. please run the code before you make any comment.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal What you said is correct, I tested your code and it is writing to the channel but we  are getting an error while reading from the channel. So, please try commenting the code of reading from the channel.

Answer (score 2):

`var x chan int` is only a declare for 'x' , you only create a val in the stack without actual memory malloc in the heap.however,

```golang
var x chan int
x = make(chan int, 0)
```

this way can actually malloc some memory in the heap for this x.

By the way, whether a val built in the stack or the heap  is telled apart fuzzily in golang. For those reference types like map,slice,chan type, they all should `make()` before put to used, or it will panic as nil point error